# Почему эти коды по-разному работают при нажатии на кнопки?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Не понимаю, почему коды ниже работаю по-разному. Что у первого когда, что у второго - функция-обработчик события `onclick` кнопок имеет одинаковое имя. Разница между первым и вторым случаями - разное количество элементов скрипт.

Вот первый код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="red">Hello!</button>
<button id="green">HelloTooo</button>
<script>
    function func(){
        alert('hello!');
    }
   document.getElementById("red").onclick=func;
  function func(){
        alert('Hello too!!!');
    }
    document.getElementById("green").onclick=func;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот второй код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="red">Hello!</button>
<button id="green">HelloTooo</button>
<script>
    function func(){
        alert('hello!');
    }
    document.getElementById("red").onclick=func;
</script>
<script>
    function func(){
        alert('Hello too!!!');
    }
    document.getElementById("green").addEventListener('click', func, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: В первом случае идёт переобъявление функции, поэтому работает всегда последняя. Во втором каждая имеет своё место

Comment: А ничего, что вы переопределяете функцию? если у вас будет две строки кода: `var a = 10; var a = 100;` вас не удивит, что в итоге значение переменной **a** будет равно 100? С функциями та же история.

Comment: первый случай мне понятен. а второй - нет. поэтому и задал вопрос

Comment: вы описали только первый случай - это "затирание". функция вторая "затирает" одноименную первую функцию

Answer (score 3):

[Определения функций поднимаются вверх текущего блока *<script>* либо файла.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)

В первом случае при поднятии функция объявленная позже просто перекроет объявленную выше поэтому фактически всегда присваивается последняя.

Во втором случае - во время выполнения первого блока скрипт, внутри него объявлена только одна функция, поэтому присваивается именно она, когда выполнение доходит до второго блока скрипт, функция опять переопределяется и во второй обработчик присваивается вторая функция.

Comment: а какой порядок подъема функций? Самая нижняя будет в самом верху и именно ее при вызове задействует интерпретатор?

Comment: @perfect, да, будет доступна самая последняя объявленная.

Comment: я, вообще, первый раз слышу про "подъем" функций

Comment: @Dimon, [Function declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)

Comment: если под подниманием подразумевается то, что функциональную декларацию можно использовать раньше (раньше - имеется в виду В ПРЕДЕЛАХ ЭЛЕМЕНТА СКРИПТ, в котором функциональная декларация встречается), чем она объявлена, то этот момент я понимаю. но все равно не понятно, какое это имеет отношение ко второму коду

Comment: @Dimon, я процитирую ответ: _во время выполнения первого блока скрипт, внутри него объявлена **только одна функция**, поэтому присваивается именно она_

Comment: @Grundy, непонятный какой-то ответ. этот ответ больше запутывает, чем отвечает на вопрос. в первом случае интерпретатор создал объект (перед выполнением скрипта) {alert('hello!'); } (функция-это объект), на который ссылается свойство window.func, потом сразу же поменял его на другой - { alert('Hello too!!!');} , а потом скрипт запустил. на первый объект ссылок вообще нет, он удаляется сбориком мусора.

Comment: во втором случае интерпретатор перед выполнением скрипта создал объект {alert('hello!'); } в свойстве window.func, затем скрипт отработал. потом наткнулся на второй срипт, переопределил предварительно свойстве window.func (теперь оно ссылается на объект - { alert('Hello too!!!');}) и скрипт отработал. разница между этими двумя вариантами в том, КОГДА наступает переопределение свойства window.func - ПЕРЕД выполнением инструкции document.getElementById("red").onclick=func; или ПОСЛЕ выполнения.

Comment: @Dimon, не понял эти два комментария, если ты сам нашел ответ - стоит разместить его как ответ

Answer (score -2):

В первом случае интерпретатор создал объект (перед выполнением скрипта функциональные декларации в пределах элемента "скрипт" записываются браузером в список) `{ alert('hello!'); }` (функция-это объект), на который ссылается свойство `window.func`, потом сразу же поменял его на другой - `{ alert('Hello too!!!'); }`, а потом скрипт запустил. На первый объект ссылок вообще нет, он удаляется сборщиком мусора.

Во втором случае интерпретатор перед выполнением скрипта создал объект `{ alert('hello!'); }` в свойстве `window.func`, затем скрипт отработал. Потом наткнулся на второй скрипт, переопределил предварительно свойство `window.func` (теперь оно ссылается на объект - `{ alert('Hello too!!!'); }`) и скрипт отработал. Разница между этими двумя вариантами в том, КОГДА наступает переопределение свойства `window.func` - ПЕРЕД выполнением инструкции `document.getElementById("red").onclick=func;` или ПОСЛЕ выполнения.

Comment: Если бы не было предыдущего ответа, то не понял бы о чем вы тут написали...